# child process cannot be put in the foreground process group using tcsetpgrp

Tags: c, linux, signals

I was trying to put the child process after `fork()` in the foreground process group, and I use `setpgid()` and `tcsetpgrp()` both in child process and parent process to avoid race condition. from the printed message, the foreground process group has already been made as the child process group in the parent process, but when executing the child process, the foreground process is set to process group of shell again, and an error occured when try to use `tcsetpgrp()` in child process.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGHUP, SighupHandler);
    signal(SIGCONT, SigcontHandler);
    int pid = fork();
     if (pid == 0){
        pid_t fpgid = tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO);
        fprintf(stderr, "foreground process id %d\n", fpgid);
        setpgid(0, 0);
        if(tcsetpgrp(0, getpgrp()) == -1) {
            perror("tcsetpgrp");
            exit(1);
        }
        fpgid = tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO);
        fprintf(stderr, "foreground process id %d\n", fpgid);
        fprintf(stderr, "child process pid %d, pgid %d\n", pid, getpgrp());
    }else if(pid > 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "parent process pid %d, pdid %d\n", getpid(), getpgrp());
        setpgid(pid, 0);
        if(tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, pid) == -1){
            perror("tcsetpgrp");
            exit(1);
        }
        pid_t fpgid = tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO);
        fprintf(stderr, "pgid of foreground process group %d\n", fpgid);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

teminal output

```
parent process pid 471939, pdid 471939
pgid of foreground process group 471940
foreground process id 471814 //this shell's pid
tcsetpgrp: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

If I ignore SIGTTOU before `fork()`, the child process can be successfully put in the foreground process group, but from the output above, the parent is first be executed, if it already set the child process in the foreground process group, then child process is no longer in background, so it shouldn't be sent SIGTTOU when try to use `tcsetpgrp()` right? why the foreground process group is set back to shell's process group later?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a background process block for input a la the shell's \`bg\` command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697742/how-do-i-make-a-background-process-block-for-input-a-la-the-shells-bg-command)

Comment: I think my question is the same as this one.

Comment: but I want to know why the child process is still sent a SIGTTOUT though I already put it in the foreground process group if the parent process execute first, which is the case from the terminal output